# problems with scanf("%d\n",&i)

Tags: c++, c, format, scanf, formatted-input

For this code:

```
int i;
scanf("%d\n",&i);
```

I am not able to stop my program until I input two numbers.

I think it is very strange ,I know when the input is suitable,the scanf will return 1.
When I input "12a 'Enter'","12 'Enter'2" and so on ,it is ok,the i=12,it seems that when I input something is different int or input a 'Enter' and something another,the scanf returns 1.

What am I missing?

Comment: try to reformulate and reformat your question.

Comment: I also added [tag:c++] tag since this behaviour is the same for both languages

Comment: @LihO Although `scanf` is available in [tag:C++], using `istream`s would be more appropriate. Maybe the question should be left as just [tag:C].

Answer (score 14):

**"I am not able to stop my program until I input two numbers when I use `scanf("%d\n",&i);`"**
Although this format makes `scanf` read the number and store it into `i`, this "reading" continues and it lasts till non-whitespace character followed by `\n` is found. This is the reason why input `1 2` makes this `scanf` stop.

You should not specify newline in the input format in this case.
Use `scanf("%d",&i);` instead.

Comment: Thank you,I never do that,and I just want to know the reason.

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the `'\n` in the scanf...
If you want to move into a new line, just put :

```
printf ("\n");
```

and it'll give u an empty line...

Answer (score 0):

**scanf("%d\n",&i);**

read the number till non-whitespace character appear(ignore all whitespace and '\n' after the number).